# Getting list of all regions in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

How can i get a list of all regions listed in windows phone 8. I couldn't find and API like **RegionInfo.GetAllRegions**. Neither there is an API to get all culture info. Is this possible via API. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to grab all the regions from the `settings` as far as i know. Where as you could only get the current region of your device.

```
System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.EnglishName
```

for more refer here:

[Retreive the country/region name in Windows Phone](http://www.ginktage.com/2011/06/retreive-the-country-name-in-windows-phone-7/)

Comment: Was aware about this. Needed an API which could fetch me the list of all regions. Guess not possible on WP8.